# How to launch Azure Remote App client on Windows 7

Tags: azure, clickonce, remoteapp

Hi I am trying out Microsoft Azure Remote App Services.It asks me to download a client to connect to remote app server to run the apps on my local machine. I downloaded the cleint (rdClickOnceLauncher.application), but this doesn't launch and asks for an associated program to open with. I am not sure how to open such programs. Could any one guide me?

OS:Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you please tell me what browser you are using and whether this is 32bit or 64bit OS?

Comment: I am using Chrome and my OS is 64-bit.

Comment: What associated program does it ask for?

Comment: It asks to choose a program to open the .application file with and I am not sure what program will open such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nailed it. It open with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\dfshim.dll" for 32 bit systems and C:\windows\sysWOW64\dfshim.dll for 64 bit systems clickonce application deployment support library.

Comment: Great! Mark your own answer as accepted answer to help fellow SO users find solutions :)